# java arithmetic

Tags: java, math, integer-overflow

why this code returns wrong value?

```
int i=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
long l=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
System.out.println(l);
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: byte b1=100;
        //byte b2=200;   // possible loss of precision
        byte b3=100+1;
        //byte b4=127+1;  // possible loss of precision
         
        int i1=2000000000;
        //int i2=2999999999; //integer number too large: 2999999999
        int i3=2000000000+1;
        int i4=2147483647+1;                                      and now I do not understand why different types of errors. for b4 variable - there is an error, for the i4 - no error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add 1 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it overflows and wraps around to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

This happens because Java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent integers. An example in 4 bits:

```
0000 : 0
0001 : 1
...
0111 : 7 (max value)
1000 : -8 (min value)
...
1110 : -2
1111 : -1
```

So when you add 1 to `0111` (max) it goes to `1000`, and that's the minimum. Expand this idea to 32-bits and it works the same way.

---

As for why your `long` is also showing an incorrect result, it's because it's performing addition on `int` s and *then* implicitly converting to `long`. You need to do:

```
long l = (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1
System.out.println(l); // now prints the correct value
```

Comment: Please tell me whether I understood the algorithm parsing this code virtual machine:
long l = Integer.MAX_VALUE +1;

1. long l - I said virtual machine to allocate 64 bits of memory for this variable.
2. Integer.MAX_VALUE +1 - in this line of virtual machine does not know anything about the variable l. Here a simple arithmetic operation, the result of which - an integer overflow.
3. in a memory area of 64 bits (l variable) written expression result from 2nd row - 32 bit incorrect value.

I see that we have no logical connection between the first and the second step?
its true?

Answer (score 3):

As the name says `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the max value available for an `Integer`. In java when an Integer goes over its max value by 1 (or overflows by 1) then its value will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Beware, with Float or Double you won't have this overflow, the value will be `POSITIVE_INFINITY`

> An operation that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation that underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN.

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - MIN_VALUE & MAX_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/javalang.doc6.html#2390)
- [Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18.2)

Answer (score 2):

You are overflowing the 32 bit integer type here by trying to store a value that cannot be represented by this type (2^31 - 1):

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java integer is 32 bit signed type ranges from: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

You can't set `i` integer variable as you did in `i=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;`

Comment: and what happens in this case:long l=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
now l is 64 bits.